# Api object in Genexus returns Method Not Allowed

Tags: api, rest, yaml, http-status-code-405, genexus

can anyone help me?

It is my first time creating an API Object in Genexus. I've already yaml archive:

[image]

[image]

I need to test in Postman but I received this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you a re using IIS try this:

How To change the IIS configuration to use PUT and DELETE in API object:

You change the verbs in the IIS configuration, in the "Extensionless-URLHandling-Integrated" you double click, you go to Restrictions / Verbs and you have to add PUT and DELETE (or select ALL verbs)
You have to change it at the Server level (Default Web site)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your endpoint doesn't support "post" request. In the image I only see a "get" declaration...so you have to change POST to GET on your Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, the API object was defined as GET, that was wrong, so I made it POST and now it is working.